# Filling Value to ListBox in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I need a simple way to fill the value from database of the current item being added so that I can use it later :

```
'Filling the MAIN Categories part
Dim DataAdapterCatm As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,title From catM;", MySqlConnection)
Dim dsMc As New DataTable
DataAdapterCatm.Fill(dsMc)
For counter = 0 To dsMc.Rows.Count - 1
    LbMCat.Items.Add(dsMc.Rows(counter).Item("title").ToString)
    'LbMCat.ValueMember = dsMc.Rows(counter).Item("id").ToString
'The above line don't work, I need something to replace it
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding what [ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember.aspx) means.  ValueMember is a string which represents the property that you wish to use as the value.  In your case it would be just `"id"`.  Notice that it is a property of the `ListBox` - it is not different for each time.

`ValueMember` and the related `DisplayMember` are only valid when using DataBinding with the [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx) property and it not valid when manually adding items to the ListBox via `Items.Add`.   What you want is the following:

```
Dim DataAdapterCatm As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id,title From catM;", MySqlConnection)
Dim dsMc As New DataTable
DataAdapterCatm.Fill(dsMc)
LbmCat.DataSource = dsMc;
LbMCat.ValueMember = "id";
LbmCat.DisplayMember = "title";
```

Comment: And how do I catch the selectedvalue as now it throws an error of DataView to String error

Comment: `SeletedValue` should be a string in code above.  Try placing the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` assignments above the `DataSource` assignment.

Comment: Again error, Here is the error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

try this in place of both lines in your for loop:

```
LbMCat.Items.Add(New ListItem(dsMc.Rows(counter).Item("title").ToString(), dsMc.Rows(counter).Item("id").ToString())
```

In the constructor for `ListItem` you can specifiy both the value and the text for the `ListItem`

Comment: Can you help me creating the constructor ?

Comment: I did as you told me; here is the constrtuctor :
    Public Class ListItem
        Shared id As String
        Shared title As String
    End Class